# Do knocked out companions get the full experience?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In Dragon Age 2, do your party members still get the full XP if they get killed in a battle?

If not, what about if they get resurrected with "regroup"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All companions earn experience, even if they're not in your party. It doesn't matter if they're knocked out.

This means you can safely try out different companions, you don't miss out XP if you switch companions.

Comment: This pretty much happens in pretty much all BioWare RPGs. I know it did in KotOR, Mass Effect and Jade Empire, I think it also happened in Baldur's Gate and NWN.

Comment: in DA:O, knocked out companions got 90% of the XP, source http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Experience#Dead_party_members But i wasn't sure about DA2